# Spring classes hierarchy

Tags: java, spring

Spring architecture is self-explanatory, but I digging into depth of spring and trying to find spring class’s hierarchy like java collection hierarchy, all information like which is parent class which interfaces its implementing, up to child classes but I haven't found any suitable diagram or call hierarchy from which I can understand.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @GokcenG Eclipse JUNO

Comment: You can try UML Lab, Green UML or ObjectAid for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has different modules for different purposes. Here is the tree hierarchy for all packages in springframework.

[Class Hierarchy for Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/overview-tree.html) - Scroll Down to **`Class Hierarchy`** Section

Hope this is what you want.